# Verilog always block properties - sequential vs. combinatorial

Tags: verilog, hdl

I understand that `always` block can be used to implement procedural and sequential logic.

1. Will the **gate-level** realization of the following two codes be the same? If yes, what is the correct way of describing this continuous-time logic?

a.

```
module func(input a, input b , output reg o);
   always @(a,b)
    o=a&b;
endmodule
```

b.

```
module func(input, a, input b, output o);
   assign o = a & b;
endmodule
```

In (a), 'o' is a reg type and in (b) it is a wire. What does this difference mean?

2. What are the required 'always' block properties for the synthesis tool to implement a FF? I know the following will result in a FF:

```
always @(posedge clk or negedge rst)
      [...]
```

But, I'm looking for a more in-depth understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your (a) and (b) codes are functionally equivalent.  This means that they will simulate the same way and they will infer the same logic when synthesized.

They use 2 different styles of modeling: (a) uses a **procedural** assignment because it uses an `always` block, whereas (b) uses a **continuous** assignment because there is no `always` block and it uses the `assign` keyword.

In this simple case, there is no "correct" way; they are 2 different styles to achieve the same functionality.  For such simple logic, it is preferable to use (b) because it uses less code and it is easier to understand.  However, if your combinational logic were more complicated, the procedural approach might be easier to understand.

In (a), the `o` signal must be a `reg` type since it is assigned inside a procedural logic block.  There is no such requirement for continuous assignments.  In this case, defining a `reg` type does not result in a flip-flop.  A `reg` only infers a flip-flop when the `always` block describes sequential logic

Synthesis tools look for specific types of patterns in Verilog code to infer sequential logic.  The following will infer flip-flops with an **asynchronous** reset:

```
always @(posedge clk or negedge rst)
    if (!rst) ...
    else ...
```

The following will infer flip-flops with a **synchronous** reset:

```
always @(posedge clk)
    if (!rst) ...
    else ...
```

These are just a couple examples.